# Realm migration needed: occasionally error

Tags: android, migration, realm

I have the app that has been production released

Realm version I'm currently using is 1.1.0

After adding Firebase crash reporting I started to get strange errors:

> io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: The
>   MedicineSchedulerItem class is missing from the schema for this Realm.
>
> Unable to start receiver
>   BootReceiver:
>   io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: The
>   MedicineSchedulerItem class is missing from the schema for this Realm.

Realm migration procedure

```
@Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        if (oldVersion == 0) {

            schema
                    .get("DoctorVisit")
                    .addField("docType", String.class);

            oldVersion++;

        }

        if (oldVersion == 1) {

            schema
                    .create("Message")
                    .addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)

                    .addField("text_ru", String.class)
                    .addField("text_en", String.class)
                    .addField("text_ua", String.class)

                    .addField("title_ru", String.class)
                    .addField("title_en", String.class)
                    .addField("title_ua", String.class)

                    .addField("date", long.class)
                    .addField("download", int.class)
                    .addField("isVisible", Boolean.class)
                    .addField("isRead", Boolean.class);

            oldVersion++;

        }

        if (oldVersion == 2) {

            schema.get("DoctorVisit")
                    .addField("useNotifications", boolean.class);

            schema.create("MedicineSchedulerItem")
                    .addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("parentId", String.class)
                    .addField("masterId", String.class)
                    .addField("dosage", float.class)
                    .addField("time", long.class)
                    .addField("alarmId", int.class)
                    .addField("isVisible", boolean.class);

            schema
                    .create("MedicineCourse")
                    .addField("id", String.class, FieldAttribute.PRIMARY_KEY)
                    .addField("userId", String.class)
                    .addField("profileId", String.class)
                    .addField("comment", String.class)
                    .addField("isVisible", boolean.class)
                    .addField("updateTime", long.class)
                    .addField("title", String.class)
                    .addField("manufacturingForm", int.class)
                    .addField("dosage", float.class)
                    .addField("measurementUnit", int.class)
                    .addField("dateStart", long.class)
                    .addField("duration", int.class)
                    .addField("takingIntervalDays", int.class)
                    .addField("takingTime", long.class)
                    .addField("takingTimeType", long.class)
                    .addField("useNotifications", boolean.class)
                    .addRealmObjectField("medicine", schema.get("Medicine"))
                    .addRealmListField("scheduler", schema.get("MedicineSchedulerItem"))
                    .addRealmListField("dayScheduler", schema.get("MedicineSchedulerItem"));


            oldVersion++;

        }

    }
```

Most of devices work properly, migration process last the way it should. 
But in some rare cases I get the error I've mentioned above.

I use 'Realm.getDefaultInstance()' for getting realm instance, startup initialization:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .name(Realm.DEFAULT_REALM_NAME)
                .schemaVersion(3)
                .migration(new ProjectRealmMigration())
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
```

Comment: sounds like multiprocess access of Realm

Comment: could be multiprocess issue, this version of Realm is old, could also be this issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/3409 fixed after 1.1.0

Comment: @crd, can you confirm that this is not simply a problem of accessing a single Realm object from multiple threads?

Comment: It's definitely not because of accessing realm object from multiple threads. 
I have updated project with realm version 3.0.0. After publishing app I'll write whether it helps or not.

Comment: Unfortunately it has not solved the problem. Realm version is 3.0.0. 
99% errors I get on Samsung devices at boot broadcast receiver (from where realm instance is accessed)

Comment: got any solution over it?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your RealmObject class has any non-nullable values (without the ?), if so, be sure to set the `FieldAttribute.REQUIRED` to those properties.

I had the same issue and somehow when using kotlin data types, for some devices it works and for others it doesn't (as you mention. So you need to specify the non-nullability.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a multiprocess issue. This error simply appears because you updated your Realm Objects Interface (Realm Schema). If you don't want to use migrations to fix the problem, you can fix it by going to AVD Manager, selecting the virtual device you use, click the arrow on right and click "wipe data".
**NOTE**: this will delete any other data you have on this device so you might consider creating new virtual device instead.